# Use DI ( Dagger 2/Hilt ) at runtime without broke MVVM pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

suppose i need to let user login at runtime using MVVM and DI patterns
and i have Repository that have function to make login

```
class RepositoryLogin @Inject constructor() {
    fun login(login: Login){
        ...
    }
}
```

Now we need ViewModel that pass this Login object to our Repository at runtime, here is some of my solution:

1. Use @AssistedInject to construct ViewModel at runtime with parameters
   and call "login" function that creates inside in viewModel an istance of Login class. But in this case we broke DI pattern, create new instance without passing throught constructor or method.

```
class Foo4ViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted("username") val username: String,
    @Assisted("password") val password: String,
    val repositoryLogin: RepositoryLogin
) : ViewModel() {

    companion object{
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: Foo4ViewModelFactory,
            username: String,
            password: String,
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory{
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                val login = Login(username, password)
                return assistedFactory.create(username,password) as T
            }
        }
    }

    fun login(){
        // !! Login is passed without DI so we can't change him during test -> Broke DI pattern
        repositoryLogin.login(Login( username = username, password = password))
    }

}
@AssistedFactory
interface Foo4ViewModelFactory{
    fun create(
        @Assisted("username")username: String,
        @Assisted("password")password: String,
    ) : Foo4ViewModel
}
```

2. We could make much simple but problem is the same

```
@HiltViewModel
class Foo4ViewModel constructor(
    val repositoryLogin: RepositoryLogin
) : ViewModel() { 
    fun login(username : String, password : String){
        // still Login is passed without DI so we can't change him during test -> Broke DI pattern
        repositoryLogin.login(Login( username = username, password = password))
    }
}
```

3. Passing Login istance to viewModel through @AssistedInject or like parameter to login method but in this case our activity/fragment (view) have reference to model and this broke MVVM pattern

```
@HiltViewModel
class Foo4ViewModel constructor(
    val repositoryLogin: RepositoryLogin
) : ViewModel() { 
    fun login(login : Login){
        // probably we dont broke DI rules
        repositoryLogin.login(login)
    }
}
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var username : String,
    private lateinit var password : String,
    private val foo4ViewModel : Foo4ViewModel by viewModels

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        
    }

    fun onClickListener(){
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener {
            // !! View have reference to model -> Broke MVVM pattern
            foo4ViewModel.login(Login(username, password))
        }
    }
...

}
```

There is elegant solution that doesn't broke DI and MVVM patterns?
If not, how should i handle this situation?

Comment: nothing wrong with passing both the username and password via the login method on your viewmodel (i.e. your approach #2). you can write any tests perfectly fine. referencing your viewmodel in your view does not break the mvvm pattern either.

Comment: @takecare the problem of case #3 was not about that view have reference for viewmodel but that view have reference to Model: Login(username, password)